# VSTS: add domain user that is not in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, tfvc, git-tf

I am trying to add a user into our VSTS.  This user is a domain account on the company's Azure AD, which is connected to VSTS.  The user does not show up in the directory.  I imagine they no longer are with the company.  However, I am trying to add them so that I can use git-tf to import a repository in TFVC format and use the --keep-author argument.

How can I add this user to VSTS and if I cannot, how should I proceed?  I suppose I could create a nondomain email and map this user in the git-tf USERMAP file, but I'm not sure of the best course of action here.

Update: the git-tf mapping is not always working for me.  I have added many users from the source repository but only some of them moved to the [mapped] section.  Several are still in [unmapped] and one user I cannot add to VSTS because I believe it is a deactivated/deleted Azure AD account, so the add user process fails, saying "Aad guest invitation failed".

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, I worked around it for now.  The git-tf mapping was not mapping all of the users, some of which were in both environments.  So I just switched to the --ignore-author flag so it wouldn't bother trying to map checkins to authors.  It makes the finished product worse, but I could not justify billing additional hours banging my head against a wall for a product that appears to just not be working correctly with regards to this area.

Answer (score 1):

You can add guest user to AD in azure portal.

[Add guest users to a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/add-users-administrator#add-guest-users-to-a-group)